# Given a library function how can I get its file offset?

Tags: function, shared-libraries, offset, nm, addr2line

Using backtrace and backtrace_symbols, I can get a mangled function name of interest (lets call it funcA_mangledName that belongs to libfsw.so.

My goal is to get the source file and line number where it is defined. I can do this for functions that are not defined in a library file as shown below. stacktrace holds the backtrace. filename = S_main_executable in regular cases.

```
sprintf(syscom[jj], "addr2line %p -e %s", stacktrace[jj], filename);
system(syscom[jj]);
```

However, this does not work when the function is part of a library, ie filename = libfsw.so.

Working backwards I can do this on a linux terminal:

```
nm libfsw.so | grep funcA_mangledName
```

to get: 000000000020cbea T funcA_mangledName

Then when I enter in the linux terminal:

```
addr2line 0x000000000020cbea -e libfsw.so
```

I get the correct source file and line number.

What am I missing to from the beginning to that correct file offset number?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out! I am able to convert the "virtual address" given by backtrace into a file offset, by subtracting the virtual base address of the library file. I'm assuming as long as the library is loaded into continuous memory, this should always work.

```
for (jj=2; jj < trace_size; ++jj) {
   void *handle;
   struct link_map *map;

   handle = dlopen(filename, RTLD_LAZY);
   dlinfo(handle, RTLD_DI_LINKMAP, &map);

   // Override the address given by backtrace (only needed for library files)
   stacktrace[jj] = stacktrace[jj] - map->l_addr;

   sprintf(syscom[jj], "addr2line %p -e %s", stacktrace[jj], filename);
   system(syscom[jj]);
   dlclose(handle);
}
```

Comment: I came across this exact issue but can't figure out how to identify whether an address belongs to a library file or not... had you figured this out?

Comment: I think I know what you're asking. In my case, I'm dealing with trying to get Floating Point Exception (FPE) file name and line number information. In my case, I get the backtrace addresses into stacktrace. I use: frames = backtrace(stacktrace, 10);  char ** symbolStrings = backtrace_symbols(stacktrace, frames); Inside the symbolStrings array, you can check to see if you find ".so". If you do, your stacktrace address is part of this library. You can parse out the full library filename, open it as shown above, and get the map->l_addr.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if there's another way that doesn't involve comparing strings. Surely the runtime has the address space for each library somewhere... it must be query-able